# Django FormView and ListView multiple inheritance error

Tags: python, django

**Problem**

I mad a `AccesCheck` Mixin, and view named `ListFormView` that inherits `AccessCheck`, `FormView` and `ListView` to show list and create/update `Worker` objects.
But when I try to add new data by POST method, django keeps returning `Attribute Error : Worker object has no attribute 'object_list'` error.

What is more confusing to me is that whole `ListFormView` is duplication of another class based view that is used in another app, and the original one is running without any problems. I've doublechecked all my codes and still have no clue to fix this problem.

**[AccessCheck]**

```
class AccessCheck(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, View):
    def test_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        access = [x.id for x in Auth.objects.filter(auth_id = self.kwargs['target'])]
        return self.request.user.is_superuser or selr.request.user.id in access

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['shop'] = Shop.objects.get(shop_id = self.kwars['shop_id'])
        return context
```

**[ListFormView]**

```
class ListFormView(AccessCheck, FormView, ListView):
    template_name = 'my_template_name.html'
    context_object_name = 'workers'
    form_class = WorkerForm
    success_url = './my_url'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Worker.objects.filter(shop_id = self.kwargs['shop_id'])
```

**How it was solved**

**[ListFormView]**

```
class ListFormView(AccessCheck, FormView, ListView):
    template_name = 'my_template_name.html'
    context_object_name = 'workers'
    form_class = WorkerForm
    success_url = './my_url'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = Worker.objects.filter(shop_id = self.kwargs['shop_id'])
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Worker.objects.filter(shop_id = self.kwargs['shop_id'])
```

Comment: @ViaTech error occurred on AccessCheck's get_context_data, when calling `super().get_context_data(**kwargs)`
I searched through and fixed this problem with overriding `get_context_data` again in my `ListFormView` with force assigning self.object_list, but still not getting why my previous code didn't work.

Comment: I'd suggest changing class names for your `Worker` view. You call `Worker.objects.filter(shop_id...)` inside of the view, while if that call is accurate you are naming your view and your model the same...this can produce namespace errors and is pretty certain why you got the error: `Worker object has no attribute 'object_list'` as the interpretor thinks you are calling your view which naturally doesn't have that attribute

Comment: @ViaTech I made typo there, class `Worker` was supposed to be `ListFormView` just as the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's classic problem of OOP. You have two inherited classes with the same method `get_context_data()`. The target class always getting code of the method from first inherited class. In this case `ListFormView.get_context_data()` has the same code as the `AccessCheck.get_context_data()` and `ListFormView` class doesn't konw anithing about code in `AccessCheck.get_context_data()` method (where `self.object_list = ...` is defined).

Here is example:

```py
class First:
    def f(self):
        print('Code from First')

class Second:
    def f(self):
        print('Code from Second')

class A(First, Second):
    pass


A().f() >>> "Code from First"
```

The possible solutions is to move correct class to the top of inheritance list:

```py
#         ╔═══════╗  swithch them
class A(Second, First):
    pass

A().f() >>> "Code from Second"
```

Or you can define your own f method in class A and use super with argument to define where you wanted to start method resoulution. To define what to write as first argument of super run `A.__mro__` and chose class before target in this list:

```py
class A(First, Second):    
    def f(self):
        super(First, self).f()

A.__mro__ >>> (<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.First'>, <class '__main__.Second'>, <class 'object'>)
A().f() >>> "Code from Second"
```

I recommended you to read about OOP in python and multiple inheritance.

* your possible solution is

```py
# make from this line
class ListFormView(AccessCheck, FormView, ListView)
# this one
class ListFormView(ListView, AccessCheck, FormView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance is a rich source of bugs if you don't make everything except the last superclass a Mixin class (derived from `object`). I'd have suggested

```
class AccessCheckMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
    # merging two mixins and adding methods is fine
    def test_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        access = [x.id for x in Auth.objects.filter(auth_id = self.kwargs['target'])]
        return self.request.user.is_superuser or selr.request.user.id in access

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        return redirect('index')

    # get_context_data belongs in a View subclass

class ListFormView(AccessCheckMixin, FormView, ListView):
    # I have misgivings about merging FormView and ListView, but maybe 
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # it belongs here, but super() is going to invoke only one of the
        # get_context_data implemenations in one of its parents.
```

Bookmark [Classy Class-based views](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.1/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) for browsing what's in the Django CBVs.